# EXT JS transforming alphanumerics

Tags: json, coldfusion, extjs

Hi I have an ext js datagrid that is used to sort and filter that has been working fine but a user has spotted a bug and I cannot work out what it is?

one of the itemID(products) looks like this = 98694E130 but this is showed as 986940000000000.

Could you help please - let me know if I need to post the code.

Thanks in advance

code as below:

...

```
var material_colModel = new Ext.grid.ColumnModel([
        {header: "#JSStringFormat(lang_rb.material)#",                  width: 75,  sortable: true,                 dataIndex: "MATERIAL",                  filter: {}},
        {header: "#JSStringFormat(lang_rb.materialDescription)#",       width: 200, sortable: true,                 dataIndex: 'MATERIALDESCRIPTION',       filter: {}},
        {header: "#JSStringFormat(lang_rb.EANcode)#",                   width: 100, sortable: true,                 dataIndex: 'EANCODE',                   filter: {}},
        {header: "#JSStringFormat(lang_rb.SKU)#",                       width: 60,  sortable: true,                 dataIndex: 'SKU',                       filter: {}},
        {header: "#JSStringFormat(lang_rb.UPC)#",                       width: 50,  sortable: false,                dataIndex: 'UNITSPERCARTON',                    align: 'right', css: 'background-color: ##f9f9f9;'},
        {header: "#JSStringFormat(lang_rb.price)# (#currencySymbol#)",  width: 50,  sortable: false,                dataIndex: 'UNITPRICE',                         align: 'right', renderer: fmtValue, css: 'background-color: ##f9f9f9;'},
        {header: "#JSStringFormat(lang_rb.productClassificationCode)#", width: 50,  sortable: true, hidden: false,  dataIndex: 'PRODUCTCLASSIFICATIONCODE', filter: {}},
        {header: "#JSStringFormat(lang_rb.productClassification)#",     width: 175, sortable: true, hidden: false,  dataIndex: 'PRODUCTCLASSIFICATIONDESC', filter: {}},
        {header: "#JSStringFormat(lang_rb.superCategoryCode)#",         width: 50,  sortable: true, hidden: false,  dataIndex: 'SUPERCATEGORYCODE',         filter: {}},
        {header: "#JSStringFormat(lang_rb.superCategory)#",             width: 175, sortable: true, hidden: false,  dataIndex: 'SUPERCATEGORYDESC',         filter: {}},
        {header: "#JSStringFormat(lang_rb.categoryCode)#",              width: 50,  sortable: true, hidden: false,  dataIndex: 'CATEGORYCODE',              filter: {}},
        {header: "#JSStringFormat(lang_rb.category)#",                  width: 175, sortable: true, hidden: false,  dataIndex: 'CATEGORYDESC',              filter: {}},
        {header: "#JSStringFormat(lang_rb.internalClassificationCode)#",width: 50,  sortable: true, hidden: false,  dataIndex: 'INTERNALCLASSIFICATIONCODE', filter: {}},
        {header: "#JSStringFormat(lang_rb.internalClassification)#",    width: 175, sortable: true, hidden: false,  dataIndex: 'INTERNALCLASSIFICATIONDESC', filter: {}},
        {header: "#JSStringFormat(lang_rb.brandCode)#",                 width: 50,  sortable: true, hidden: false,  dataIndex: 'BRANDCODE',                 filter: {}},
        {header: "#JSStringFormat(lang_rb.brand)#",                     width: 125, sortable: true, hidden: false,  dataIndex: 'BRANDDESC',                 filter: {}},
        {header: "#JSStringFormat(lang_rb.familyBrandCode)#",           width: 50,  sortable: true, hidden: false,  dataIndex: 'FAMILYBRANDCODE',           filter: {}},
        {header: "#JSStringFormat(lang_rb.familyBrand)#",               width: 175, sortable: true, hidden: false,  dataIndex: 'FAMILYBRANDDESC',           filter: {}},
        {header: "#JSStringFormat(lang_rb.licensorCode)#",              width: 50,  sortable: true, hidden: false,  dataIndex: 'LICENSORCODE',              filter: {}},
        {header: "#JSStringFormat(lang_rb.licensor)#",                  width: 175, sortable: true, hidden: false,  dataIndex: 'LICENSORDESC',              filter: {}},
        {header: "#JSStringFormat(lang_rb.propertyCode)#",              width: 50,  sortable: true, hidden: false,  dataIndex: 'PROPERTYCODE',              filter: {}},
        {header: "#JSStringFormat(lang_rb.property)#",                  width: 175, sortable: true, hidden: false,  dataIndex: 'PROPERTYDESC',              filter: {}}
     ]);

    var myCFReader =  new Ext.data.JsonReader({
        idProperty: 'MATERIAL',
        root: 'ROWS',
        successProperty:'SUCCESS',      // CF returns Json variable names in uppercase
        messageProperty: 'MESSAGE',
        totalProperty: 'RECORDCOUNT',


    // the fields config option will internally create an Ext.data.Record
    // constructor that provides mapping for reading the record data objects
    fields: [
    {name: 'MATERIAL',                      type:'string'},
    {name: 'MATERIALDESCRIPTION',           type:'string'},
    {name: 'EANCODE',                       type:'string'},
    {name: 'SKU',                           type:'string'},
    {name: 'UNITSPERCARTON',                type:'int'},
    {name: 'UNITPRICE',                     type:'float'},
    {name: 'PRODUCTCLASSIFICATIONCODE',     type:'string'},
    {name: 'PRODUCTCLASSIFICATIONDESC',     type:'string'},
    {name: 'SUPERCATEGORYCODE',             type:'string'},
    {name: 'SUPERCATEGORYDESC',             type:'string'},
    {name: 'CATEGORYCODE',                  type:'string'},
    {name: 'CATEGORYDESC',                  type:'string'},
    {name: 'INTERNALCLASSIFICATIONCODE',    type:'string'},
    {name: 'INTERNALCLASSIFICATIONDESC',    type:'string'},
    {name: 'BRANDCODE',                     type:'string'},
    {name: 'BRANDDESC',                     type:'string'},
    {name: 'FAMILYBRANDCODE',               type:'string'},
    {name: 'FAMILYBRANDDESC',               type:'string'},
    {name: 'LICENSORCODE',                  type:'string'},
    {name: 'LICENSORDESC',                  type:'string'},
    {name: 'PROPERTYCODE',                  type:'string'},
    {name: 'PROPERTYDESC',                  type:'string'}      ]
});

//The Proxy object will specify URLs to call for different CRUD operations
var proxy = new Ext.data.HttpProxy({
    method:'POST',                
    api:{
        read:   'remote/stsRemote.cfc?method=readMaterialMasterJson'
    }
});
```

...

sorry if the formatting looks off

Comment: Which field is the one affected?

Comment: code as above - as you can see MATERIAL is of type string.  I also found that if I replace E with any other letter, it works fine - is this a mathematical thing ie:10^6? sorry MATERIAL is the problem field

Comment: It does look like math thing. What do you see in raw JSON response?

Comment: Raw Json looks like this: " 986940000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"  Note this is returned ok outside EXT JS/json

Comment: There you go - if your server returns it this way how ExtJs can show it differently? Do you have control over server side?

Comment: sorry i don't think you read me well - I said the server returns the correct record if I call my object outside Ext JS...and it is also returned ok if I replace the 'E' with for example 'A'

Comment: Yes. I misread this. Are you saying that server returns different JSON response to ExtJs and to something else?

Comment: Yes the server(stored proc) returns '98694E130' and when read in json/ext js it becomes the above number with zeros.

Comment: That doesn't make sense. Server generates JSON and sends it to the client. Can you post that JSON text? You can see it in firebug or in chrome console panel where you debug your response.

Comment: MESSAGE
 "Success"
 
RECORDCOUNT
 1
 
ROWS
 [Object { MATERIALDESCRIPTION="My desc", UNITPRICE=11.4, SUPERCATEGORYCODE="INFNT", more...}]
 
0
 Object { MATERIALDESCRIPTION="My desc", UNITPRICE=11.4, SUPERCATEGORYCODE="INFNT", more...}
 
BRANDCODE
 "PYA"
 
MATERIAL
 " 986940000000000"
 
MATERIALDESCRIPTION
 "My desc"
 
 
SUCCESS

Comment: And what is the same server returns to non-ExtJs calls?

Comment: It returns 98694E130 - and this is what I need ExtJs to return

Comment: How is the same server code returns different values for different clients? Are you accessing it from non-ExtJs client using same JSON interface?

Answer (score 0):

This is because JavaScript interprets `98694E130` as `98694*10^130`. This is called 'scientific notation'. To avoid that, make sure your value is a string and is never involuntarily cast to integer (or any numeric type)

From your comments it seems that in your JSON returned from server the `98694E130` value for `MATERIAL` column is not quoted, and hence JavaScript interprets it as a number.

Answer (score 0):

If your function's returnType is 'struct' and you're using the 'returnFormat=JSON' attribute on the function, you may want to try this:

Change your return type to "string", returnFormat to "plain", and then cfreturn SerializeJSON(struckObj)

I have found this will sometimes solve issues like this.

Comment: Hi Josh, that did not work for me unfortunately and would require me to reformat the whole code...I will try to force the record as a pure string...thanks

Comment: I fixed this by appending a space before and after the said field so like:  materialList.MATERIAL =  " " & toString(Detail.MATERIAL) & " " ; and that fixed it. and this is done in my CFC  thanks for all your help though